# How to set file name to default when downloaded with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, web

Just started using powershell on windows 7 and I want to download a file from a site that doesn't include the name of the file in the url. Right now I am using

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$src = "http://just-some-short-url/"
$dest = "C:\Users\Downloads\some-file-2.53.jar"
$webclient.DownloadFile($src,$dst)
```

And this works but only because I specify the name with some hard-coded value. But I really just want to say

```
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$src = "http://just-some-short-url/"
$dest = "C:\Users\Downloads\"
$webclient.DownloadFile($src,$dst)
```

So that whatever version is downloaded would just be named such in the `C:\Users\Downloads\` so for example next month when there is a new update to the file I get from the same link presumably I would then have a file named `some-file-2.54.jar` However the latter code throws an error and is only fixed by hard coding the file name.

Comment: Get-Help Invoke-WebRequest  ...if you are on v3+

Comment: Do the URL contain the filename? Incase it does, You can use Split-Path to get the filename from the URL.
`$file = Split-Path $src -leaf`

Comment: @David `download a file from a site that doesn't include the name of the file in the url`

Comment: See my answer to pretty much this exact same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125818/powershell-invoke-webrequest-how-to-automatically-use-original-file-name/25127597#25127597).