# PowerShell Core download file using the URL/headers file name

Tags: powershell

There's a few questions floating around for how to download files with PowerShell. I'm using PowerShell Core, so I cannot use my favorite method anymore: `Start-BitsTransfer`.

I see this recommended:

```
Invoke-WebRequest URL -OutFile c:\file.ext
```

However it seems suboptimal to have to give the file name. Can PowerShell/`iwr` guess the file name based on the URL path or the response headers?

I tried `Invoke-WebRequest URL` alone, but that doesn't store the file at all. From reading [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) it looks like there may be no option for that, is that correct? Is there a different one-liner in PowerShell to download a file using its original file name?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest, how to automatically use original file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125818/powershell-invoke-webrequest-how-to-automatically-use-original-file-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a switch for `Invoke-WebRequest`. The following code will work, however, to extract the name from the filepath in a single line:

```
Invoke-WebRequest $URL -OutFile "C:\$(Split-Path -Leaf $URL)"
```

[`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-6) will take a path and return either the full path to the parent container with `-Parent` argument, or the name of the file/directory at the end with the `-Leaf` argument.

However, this only works if the filename is part of the URL. If you, for example, have something like `http://server.domain.tld/download.php?id=12345`, the output file would end up being `download.php?id=12345`. It's not a one liner, but @Theo [shared an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25127597/584676) in his comment that defines a function to get the redirected URL. You can then use `Split-Path -Leaf` on that redirected URL to get the desired filename.

Comment: Unfortunate, thanks for the answer. PowerShell seems to have a good number of really head-scratching omissions/oddities which really grind my gears.

Comment: Eh, IMO this is a minor inconvenience to have to name the file. I agree it would be nice if it could try guessing the name but in most cases (for me) I end up giving files specific names for the sake of idempotency.

Comment: WARNING: If you don't `trim()` the trailing newline from the `Split-Path` subcommand, it could cause a `Illegal characters in path` error from `Invoke-WebRequest`. For more info, see [Invoke-WebRequest Error: "Illegal characters in path" when using OutFile Split-Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78125054/invoke-webrequest-error-illegal-characters-in-path-when-using-outfile-split-p/78125105#78125105)