# Invoke-WebRequest Error: "Illegal characters in path" when using OutFile Split-Path

Tags: windows, powershell

Why does `Invoke-WebRequest` give me an error when using a subcommand, yet when I copy the exact same output from that subcommand into the main command, I get no error?

Consider the following PowerShell commands:

```
$file_url = "https://github.com/vsajip/python-gnupg/releases/download/0.5.2/python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
Split-Path -Leaf "${file_url}"
```

I want to download the file from the above URL. To do this with `Invoke-WebRequest`, we must [specify where to save the file with `-OutFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218860), so I use `Split-Path` to extract the filename from the URL.

This works as expected:

```
PS C:\>  $file_url = "https://github.com/vsajip/python-gnupg/releases/download/0.5.2/python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl"

PS C:\>
PS C:\> Split-Path -Leaf "${file_url}"
python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

PS C:\>
```

Now, consider the following command to download the file:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})" "${file_url}"
```

This fails with `Illegal characters in path`

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})" "${file_url}"
Invoke-WebRequest : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})" "${file_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

PS C:\>
```

What I absolutely cannot understand, however, is that this command works:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl" "${file_url}"
```

If I literally just paste the output of the subcommand into where the subcommand is called, it works fine. How is that possible?

```
PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})" "${file_url}"
Invoke-WebRequest : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})" "${file_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

PS C:\>

PS C:\> Split-Path -Leaf "${file_url}"
python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

PS C:\> Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl" "${file_url}"
PS C:\>
```

Why does the `Invoke-WebRequest` call with the `Split-Path` subcommand fail with `Illegal characters in path?

Comment: Just because I'm curious: Is there a particular reason why you're using `${file_url}` instead of simply `$file_url`?

Comment: To Olaf's point: while `${file_url}` is always safe to use, the `{...}` enclosure is only _necessary_ for variable names containing special characters (not the case here) and inside `"..."` strings to clearly delineate variable names from subsequent characters.

Comment: Your sample input doesn't explain your symptom. `"${file_url}"` can be simplified to `${file_url}` or `$file_url` - in PowerShell - unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash - you never need to enclose stand-alone variable references passed as arguments in `"..."` - they will be passed properly even if they contain spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the subcommand is that it includes a newline at the end.

Save the output of the `Split-Path` subcommand to a variable and use `trim()` to remove the trailing newline. Then it should work.

```
$file_url = "https://github.com/vsajip/python-gnupg/releases/download/0.5.2/python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
$filename = "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})"
$filename = ${filename}.trim()
Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile "${filename}" "${file_url}"
```

Comment: `$filename = "$(Split-Path -Leaf ${file_url})"` can be simplified to `$filename = Split-Path -Leaf $file_url`. `$filename = "${filename}.trim()"` doesn't work as intended: the `.trim()` part is retained _verbatim_. You probably meant `$filename = $filename.Trim()`. Overall, it isn't clear why trimming is necessary at all - it isn't, judging by the sample input in your question.

Comment: Thanks for updating, but your question still doesn't explain your symptom, so your answer doesn't make sense. An assignment such as `$file_url = "https://github.com/vsajip/python-gnupg/releases/download/0.5.2/python_gnupg-0.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl"` would never result in a trailing newline

Comment: It's the `Split-Path` that adds the newline, I guess. Try the `Invoke-WebReqest` without the `trim()`. It throws the `Illegal characters in path` error, as shown in the OP

Comment: No, `Split-Path` doesn't add a newline. It would, however, retain a preexisting newline; e.g. `Split-Path "dir\`n/file"`

Comment: As I seem unable to replicate the issue, the only thing I can think is that the URL has a hidden newline\control character in @MichaelAltfield 's machine. Would you try `$file_url = $file_url -creplace '\P{IsBasicLatin}'` withouth trimming to see if it, too, works? (for all purposes and intents it's the same: remove non-ASCII characters, including invisible\control characters)