# Downloading latest version of file from website / Getting latest download Link from button (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, powershell, download, invoke-webrequest

I need to download the newest version of a bunch of files. That works pretty straight forward using direct links.

The links I need to use look something like this: https://d.apkpure.com/b/APK/org.telegram.messenger?version=latest
It's the link of the download button, which generates a new direct download link every time.

In the web browser this link will download the latest Telegram .apk. I can not use the direct download link in my script since it will change, and the link to the button will result in a html file.

I tried it using  curl, Invoke-Webrequest and DownloadFile(). It works seamlessly using the direct download links generated when using a web browser. I'd like to generate this download link using a script.

How do I use this download button to always get the latest file/latest download link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get final redirected url use this script:

```
$URL= "https://d.apkpure.com/b/APK/org.telegram.messenger?version=latest"
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($URL)
$request.AllowAutoRedirect=$true
$request.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.500.0 Safari/534.6' #helps with difficult pages...

try{
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $redirectedURL = $response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
    $response.Close()
} catch {
    "Error: $_"
}
```

Then you can download via Invoke-WebRequest

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $redirectedURL -OutFile ".\a.apk" -user
```

Comment: Thanks, I also referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25125818/powershell-invoke-webrequest-how-to-automatically-use-original-file-name]

Answer (score 0):

My Code:

```
            $url= "https://d.apkpure.com/b/APK/org.telegram.messenger?version=latest"
            $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
            $request.AllowAutoRedirect=$true
            $request.UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT; Windows NT 10.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.500.0 Safari/534.6' #helps with difficult pages...

            try{
                $response = $request.GetResponse()
                $redirectedURL = $response.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri
                
                $dispositionHeader = $Response.Headers['Content-Disposition']
                $disposition = [System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition]::new($dispositionHeader)
                
                $fileName = $disposition.FileName
                $response.Close()
            } catch {
                "Error: $_"
            }
            Invoke-WebRequest -URI $redirectedURL -OutFile ".\APKs\$fileName"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding.  Please consider adding some commentary as to what code does what.